# subplots overlap with plt.subplot properties

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot them side by side, but why are they overlapping?[violinplot & boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNtBa.png)

```
plt.subplot= (1,2,1)
color = sb.color_palette()[9]
order = ['Minicompact Cars', 'Subcompact Cars', 'Compact Cars', 'Midsize 
Cars','Large Cars']
sb.violinplot(data= fuel_econ, x = fuel_econ['VClass'], y = 
fuel_econ['displ'],
          inner = 'quartile', color = color, order = order)
plt.xticks(rotation = 15)

plt.subplot= (1,2,2)
sb.boxplot(data =fuel_econ, x=fuel_econ['VClass'], y = fuel_econ['displ'],
       color = color, order = order)
plt.xticks(rotation = 15);
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you want people to help, please detail as much as possible you question, and provide a minimal working example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) reproducing the problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is `plt.subplot(1,2,1)` (notice the absence of = sign)